# Logback creates empty log files

Tags: logback

I have a small problem with my logback configuration and I wonder if what I want to do is possible.
I use logback with RollingFileAppender rolling my files on a daily basis.
It works very well, but all files are recreated everyday, even if files are empty.
Is there a mean to tell logback to create a file only if something has to be written in it ?

Thanks a lot,

Seb

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719845/how-do-i-make-log4j-create-log-files-on-demand-only ?

Comment: Yes, it seems a good lead, thank you